# Is it possible to host emails on heroku?

Tags: heroku, hosting, appdomain, ovh, webmail

I currently have an OVH hosting and domain name, but I would like to change and host my app on Heroku. The thing is, I don't know how to keep my email addresses and how to host them with Heroku. I'm a total dumb on web hosting btw.

For the story, I went from a static app hosted on ovh to a dynamic app on Heroku.

Comment: No, you'd want something else. However, you can still use Heroku; you'd use MX records in your DNS to point the emails to a provider. (I use Google Apps for mine.)

Comment: You can still run your application on Heroku. I suggest looking at [the available mail addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#email-sms). In most cases, provisioning the add-on and pointing your mail code at it is enough.